# How to use KeyPressEvent in correct way

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, key

try to create HotKeys for my forms

code

```
    private void FormMain_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)        
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("e");
        }
    }
```

works for one key, but if I whant to use combination of keys like CTRL+N, try to use `if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter && e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.N)` - but it's not working. I'm I right - using such code for keys combination?

**EDIT**

[image: Edit]

This code capture only first pressed key, but not combination - so if I press CTRL + Enter - code capture CTRL but not Enter Key - try to create additional `if` but - result the same...

---

Change event from `KeyPress` to `KeyDown` - now it's work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For other combinations of `Control` and another letter, there is an interesting thing that, the `e.KeyChar` will have different code. For example, normally `e.KeyChar = 'a'` will have  code of `97`, but when pressing `Control` before pressing `a` (or `A`), the actual code is `1`. So we have this code to deal with other combinations:

```
private void FormMain_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)        
{
   //Pressing Control + N
   if(e.KeyChar == 'n'-96) MessageBox.Show("e");
   //Using this way won't help us differentiate the Enter key (10) and the J letter 
}
```

You can also use `KeyDown` event for this purpose. (In fact, `KeyDown` is more suitable). Because it supports the `KeyData` which contains the combination info of modifier keys and another literal key:

```
private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
   //Pressing Control + N
   if(e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N)) MessageBox.Show("e");
}
```

Comment: try it - modifierKeys - Ok, but instead of N key get some different result - please see Edit

Answer (score 1):

try this for combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>,

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.N)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("e");
   }
```